# Fatal error: Call to undefined method dbconnection::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

im studing php :)
In first, sorry for my bad english, I try speak normaly :)

I always start writing some code with database, but all time have problems with extends. Please help me.

index.php

```
define('CWM', TRUE);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
define('LINK', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));

require_once 'classes' . DS . 'database.php';
require_once 'classes' . DS . 'session.php';
require_once 'classes' . DS . 'core.php';
$core = new core;
```

core.php must including session and dbconnection class

```
if(!defined('CWM')) die('script access error');
class core extends session{
    protected $db;

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new dbconnection();
        parent::session();
    }
}
```

database.php class where i tried connect to database

```
class dbconnection{
protected $db;
protected $dbinfo = array();

public function connect(){
        if(file_exists(PATH . 'classes' . DS . 'config.php')){
            $this->dbinfo = require_once PATH . 'classes' . DS . 'config.php';

            try{
                $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbinfo['hostname'] . ';dbname='. $this->dbinfo['dbname'], $this->dbinfo['username'], $this->dbinfo['password'], array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
                return $this->db;
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }else{
            trigger_error('undefined config.php', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    function __destruct(){
        $this->db = NULL;
    }
}
```

session.php this class tri select information from my bd if user have a session cookie

```
if(!defined('CWM')) die('script access error');
class session extends dbconnection{
    protected $db;
    protected $member = array();

    function __construct(){
        parent::connect();
        $this->session;
    }

    protected function session(){
        $_COOKIE['session'] = 5;
        if(!empty($_COOKIE['session'])){
            $this->member = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `session` = '?'")->execute(array($_COOKIE['session']));
            var_dump($this->member);
        }else{
            $this->member = false;
        }
    }
}
```

if this posible, i need that core class includes session and database classes, and thes session class included database and core classes

Comment: `class Session extends DbConnection` **means violation** of Liskov Substitution Principle and Single Responsibility Principle. Also it breaks Separation of Concerns. If you care about code quality and maintainability you should google for these things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You're getting this error because you are calling `prepare()` on the `session::db` variable, this variable is of type `dbconnection` and so does not contain a `prepare()` method, you'd need to change your code to:</s>

```
if(!defined('CWM')) die('script access error');
class session extends dbconnection{
    protected $db;
    protected $member = array();

    function __construct(){
        parent::connect();
        $this->session;
    }

    protected function session(){
        $_COOKIE['session'] = 5;
        if(!empty($_COOKIE['session'])){
            $this->member = $this->db->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `session` = '?'")->execute(array($_COOKIE['session']));
            var_dump($this->member);
        }else{
            $this->member = false;
        }
    }
}
```

(I have added a second `->db` in order to refer to the `dbconnection::db` variable which is of type PDO

It may be worth rethinking the structure of your classes as, as you've discovered, the current structure can easily lead to confusion.

Here's a suggested structure for these classes:

Core.php

```
if(!defined('CWM')) die('script access error');
class Core extends Session {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->session();
    }
}
```

DbConnection.php

```
class DbConnection{
    protected $db;
    protected $dbinfo = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }    

    public function connect(){
        if(file_exists(PATH . 'classes' . DS . 'config.php')){
            $this->dbinfo = require_once PATH . 'classes' . DS . 'config.php';

            try{
                $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbinfo['hostname'] . ';dbname='. $this->dbinfo['dbname'], $this->dbinfo['username'], $this->dbinfo['password'], array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
                return $this->db;
            }catch(PDOException $e){
               die($e->getMessage());
           }
        }else{
            trigger_error('undefined config.php', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    function __destruct(){
        $this->db = NULL;
    }
}
```

Session.php

```
if(!defined('CWM')) die('script access error');
class Session extends DbConnection {

    protected $member = array();

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function session(){
        $_COOKIE['session'] = 5;
        if(!empty($_COOKIE['session'])){
            $this->member = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `session` = '?'")->execute(array($_COOKIE['session']));
            var_dump($this->member);
        }else{
            $this->member = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Main changes
-Removed $db variables everywhere
-Capitalised class names
-Moved setup tasks, e.g., DbConnection::connect() to constructors

Comment: What error are you getting now, is it the same one?

Comment: yes, but im find answe, im need a $this->db = parent::connect(); not  only parent::connect(); how i can close this question?

Comment: Yes I reread your code and I see why my fix didn't work. Still worth considering restructuring things though if you find thing are getting confusing. There should be a close link under the question.